# Software Updater hangs while running 'update-grub' with 100% CPU usage

Tags: 14.04, grub2, updates, update-manager

On the last couple of updates to my Ubuntu 14.04 LTS system, the installation process has got stuck at the point where the kernel image is being installed.
It's worked for my primary Ubuntu installation partition, but appears to be stuck on partition sda5, where I have an older Ubuntu version.
What's causing this, and are there any logs I can look in for clues?

Here's a screenshot of the update window. At this point it hangs, and the CPU usage goes sky high. I have to kill it before the machine shuts down due to overheating!

[image]

As requested, here's the output of `parted -l`.

```
Model: ATA SAMSUNG HM500JJ (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 500GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: msdos

Number  Start   End     Size    Type      File system     Flags
 1      32.3kB  41.1MB  41.1MB  primary   fat16           diag
 2      41.9MB  10.5GB  10.5GB  primary   ntfs            boot
 3      10.5GB  168GB   158GB   primary   ntfs
 4      168GB   500GB   332GB   extended
 5      168GB   242GB   73.4GB  logical   ext4
 8      242GB   316GB   74.0GB  logical   ext4
 7      316GB   496GB   180GB   logical   ext4
 6      496GB   500GB   4081MB  logical   linux-swap(v1)


Error: /dev/zram0: unrecognised disk label                                

Error: /dev/zram1: unrecognised disk label                                

Error: /dev/zram2: unrecognised disk label                                

Error: /dev/zram3: unrecognised disk label
```

My root partition is sda8

```
df -H
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda8        73G   46G   24G  66% /
none            4.1k     0  4.1k   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
udev            4.1G   13k  4.1G   1% /dev
tmpfs           817M  1.6M  815M   1% /run
none            5.3M     0  5.3M   0% /run/lock
none            4.1G  1.5M  4.1G   1% /run/shm
none            105M   78k  105M   1% /run/user
/dev/sda7       178G  155G   14G  92% /home
```

Comment: The process running at this point of the update is `update-grub`, a tool to detect installed systems and (re)generate the GRUB bootloader configuration files. I edited your title to reflect this. - And as it says `Found Ubuntu 11.10 ...`, I think that it's not the 11.10 installation which causes the problem, but the one which it tries to detect afterwards. What other systems do you have installed? The output of `sudo parted -l` could be useful, please [edit] your question to add it.